# ComboBox problems in java

Tags: java, swing, visibility, actionlistener, jcombobox

Can i do something like after i clicked the button then the combo box appear,the combo box only appear when i clicked the button.Is it even possible?

Here is my code:

```
search.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)  {
             if(c3.getSelectedItem()=="First Floor"){
                p1.add(c42);
            }
    });
```

The c3 is another combo box which contain from ground floor to fourth floor and c42 is combo box which contains room numbers for only First floor,i need something like when i clicked the search button then the c42 appear.

Comment: ya~it is working now~using setVisible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If c42 exists, and it's swing's ComboBox then You can simply use c42.setVisible(true).

Comment: thx a lot , with your help, i solved the problem,appreciate it